# Bigquery package throws odd error

Tags: python, pip, google-bigquery, package, conda

When doing this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

im getting this error:

```
KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.EnumDescriptorProto.EnumReservedRange.start"
```

I tried installing and uninstalling google-cloud and google-cloud-bigquery using `conda install`, `pip -install --upgrade --no-cache-dir`, `pip -install --ignore-installed` but nothing seems to be working.

It worked before i uninstalled the package though.

What shall i do in order to fix it? Shall i complately remove anaconda and install it from scratch?
Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing and then installing anaconda